# PHP: How calculate calendar days with all 42 days

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

The goal is exclusively to get a range of days, in other words
, start date and end date, as if it were a "calendar matrix", containing the 42 days, being the days of the current month, with the days of the previous month and next month. No need to present (render) a calendar, only get dates.

For example, follow image below.

I need to enter a certain month of a given year, and would need to get this range of days, as picture.

Using PHP Carbon, I easily get the days of the current month, using `startOfMonth()`, `endOfMonth()` , `subMonth()`, `addMonth()`.

Doing this, I get every day of these 3 months, but the goal is to be able to "filter" these days to present only the interval equal to a calendar, but obviously something dynamic, ie, if I use Carbon, would simply inform the desired date , and get "filtered" range, respecting the position of each "cell".

```
$prev_start = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth();
$prev_end = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth();

$start = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
$end = Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();

$next_start = Carbon::now()->addMonth()->startOfMonth();
$next_end = Carbon::now()->addMonth()->endOfMonth();
```

[image: calendar]

Comment: Just align 1 with its day, then the rest will magically fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what you can do:

```php
$monthStart = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
$monthEnd = Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();

$calendarStart = $monthStart->startOfWeek(Carbon::SUNDAY); 
$calendarEnd = $monthEnd->endOfWeek(Carbon::SATURDAY);
```

`$calendarStart` and `$calendarEnd` should now contain the first and last day that will be displayed in a single screen. This assumes that the calendar will expand the first and last week displayed.

If you are using a calendar that always shows 42 days regardless you can just do:

```php
$monthStart = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();

$calendarStart = $monthStart->startOfWeek(Carbon::SUNDAY); 
$calendarEnd = $calendarStart->addDay(42);
```

Comment: Thanks so much... That was what I was looking for... But still, if I use `setTestNow()` to change `now()`, for example `$knownDate = Carbon::create(2019, 7, 20); Carbon::setTestNow($knownDate);` and use `diffInDays()`, I won't get 42 days, but 35 days (34 + 1). If I look at any calendar in July 2019, it starts on 2019-06-30 and ends 2019-08-10. Of course it could add 7 more days if 34, but I don't know if it would be the most correct form or if it could have a false result.

Comment: By sampling, I think this is enough: 
`if ($diff < 41)
{
  echo $calendarEnd->addDay(7);
}
else {
  echo $calendarEnd;
}`

Comment: If you're talking about the windows calendar that seems to have a fixed number of days so you can probably get that by doing `$calendarStart->addDay(42)` in all cases (the end doesn't seem to matter that much

Comment: Here's a tip for anyone using an older version of Carbon, like me. I was using version 1.39, and method startOfWeek() does not accept parameter. `public function startOfWeek()
    {
        while ($this->dayOfWeek !== static::$weekStartsAt) {
            $this->subDay();
        }

        return $this->startOfDay();
    }`. As I do not want to upgrade at this time, it was necessary to use the method `setWeekStartsAt(Carbon::SUNDAY)`